# Images and textboxes on the sheet flicker by button click

Tags: excel, vba

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If ... something... Then
Range("calc02").EntireRow.Hidden = False // this is critical point
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The row is allready visible, so there is nothing to do, but images and textboxes on the sheet are repainted (they flicker). How can I prevent this flickering ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
application.screenupdating = false
'your code here
application.screenupdating = true
```

and this should solve most of these issues.

---

Add an additional if statement to check whether the row needs to be set to unhidden or not so it does not unnecessarily do so:

```
If ... something... Then
    if (Range("calc02").EntireRow.Hidden = true) then
        Range("calc02").EntireRow.Hidden = False // this is critical point
    end if
End If
```

Comment: @ enderland, I changed the question, because I forgott - I allready have the lines about ScreenUpdating.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one to remember - setting rows and columns to hidden or not hidden is really really slooooow, especially if you have to do it repeatedly. So it is always worth doing the test as described by enderland. This should help to avoid flicker, and should run faster too.